# How to open two different url in the same webview application

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android eCommerce application where i am using webview to call the responsive website into mobile application and every function works fine but when I click on PAYONLINE it opens payment gateway page in the browser. How to hide that browser and open the payment gateway page the same application ?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.prashantlaldas;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");



        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {
                                      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                                          // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                                          String data = "\n" +
                                                  "\n" +
                                                  "<div id=\"container\">\n" +
                                                  "\n" +
                                                  "<div class=\"connection-problem\">\n" +
                                                  "<p><img src=\"noconnection.png\" width=\"100px\" height=\"69px\"></p>\n" +
                                                  "\n" +
                                                  "<p>No internet connection.</br>Please Turn ON your data or wifi</p>\n" +
                                                  "<a href=\"http://www.google.com/ class=\"button\" style=\"background-color: #fff;border: none;color: #de1616;padding: 8px 22px;text-align: center;border-radius: 4px;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;cursor: pointer;border: 1px solid #de1616;\">Retry</a>\n" +
                                                  "</div>\n" +
                                                  "</div>\n" +
                                                  "<style>\n" +
                                                  ".connection-problem{text-align: center;margin-top: 50%;}\n" +
                                                  "#container {\n" +
                                                  "    display: flex;              /* establish flex container */\n" +
                                                  "    flex-direction: column;     /* stack flex items vertically */\n" +
                                                  "    justify-content: center;    /* center items vertically, in this case */\n" +
                                                  "    align-items: center;        /* center items horizontally, in this case */\n" +
                                                  "    height: 300px; \n" +
                                                  "\n" +
                                                  "}\n" +
                                                  "   \n" +
                                                  "   \n" +
                                                  "   \n" +
                                                  "\n" +
                                                  "</style>";

                                          mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/error.html", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
                                      }


                                      @Override
                                      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                          //hide loading image
                                          findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                          //show webview
                                          findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                      }


                                  }

            );



        }



        @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }



}
```

MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
package com.prashantlaldas;

/**
 * Created by oct on 10/17/2016.
 */
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by oct on 10/12/2016.
 */
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("www.google.com"))
        {
            return  false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return  true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume that you are in India. I have used you code to reproduce the issue. It loads the google.co.in in external browser.

Comment: yes I an from india

Comment: String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
            if (host.contains("www.google.co.in")) {
                return false;
            }

Comment: use contains instead of ends with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        // load URL here
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }


    /**
     * The type My web client.
     */
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // page started event
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // hide progress bar 
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrashantDas I'm glad I was able to help